# How to convert a PDOStatement to JSON and print it?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

How to convert a PDOStatement to JSON and print it?
I am implementing the following function in PHP with which I want to return an array depending on an id, but when I convert the array to json and print it, the result does not appear.

```
public static function getAllDebtorsByUser(int $id) : array {
    $query = "SELECT id_debtor Id, name_debtor Name, address_debtor Address, phone_debtor Phone from debtors where user_debtor = :i;";
    $sth = Connection::select($query, ["i" => $id]); //return a PDOStatement
    if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $debtors[] = $row;
        }
        return $debtors;
    } else
        return [];
}
```

I used the following code to convert from array to JSON. It does not mark me errors, but it does not show me the result unless I want to show a single column instead of 3.

**Example**

Code to print:

```
echo json_encode (Debtor::getAllDebtorsByUser (1)); // The function is inside a class called Debtor
```

Query:

```
SELECT id_debtor Id from debtors where user_debtor =: i;
```

Result:

```
[
    {
       "Id": "1"
    },
    {
       "Id": "2"
    }
]
```

Having the 3 columns I need and using the PHP function * print_r * shows me the correct result, but what I need is for the JSON to be seen.

**Example:**

Code to print:

```
print_r (Debtor::getAllDebtorsByUser (1));
```

Query:

```
SELECT id_debtor Id, name_debtor Name, address_debtor Address, phone_debtor Phone from debtors where user_debtor =: i;
```

Result:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 1
                [Name] => Debtor 1
                [Address] => Dir 1
                [Phone] => Tel 1
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 2
                [Name] => Debtor 2
                [Address] => Dir 2
                [Phone] => Tel 2
            )
    
    )
```

So using echo `json_encode ()` to print does not work for me unless the query has only one column.

It also does not work indicating depth to json_encode ()

** Software versions **

PHP: 7.2.12

MySQL: 5.7.24

XAMPP: 3.2.2

SO: Windows 10

Comment: You likely made a mistake in your observations or function usage. Any array that `print_r` outputs would easily pass `json_encode` alike. Store the result in a variable, then run `print_r` and `echo json_enc` on that. Showcase these results instead.

Comment: What is Connection::select? It doesn't seem like you're using raw PDO. It looks like the values for Name, Address and Phone are not plain objects or arrays so PHP doesn't know how to serialize them, that's why you get only the Id field.

Comment: What do you mean `json_encode()` "does not work?" What happens when you try to encode the results of the function? What does `json_last_error_msg()` say?

Comment: Note: you can greatly simplify your code (i.e. replacing the `if` and `while`) by using `fetchAll()`.